# .My HBASE HMASTER starts but quits in 15seconds

Tags: hbase

I have setup Hbase in a 5node cluster & configured hmaster in the same system as that of namenode.My HBASE HMASTER starts but quits in 15 seconds. Leaving region servers up & running. Any idea why this is happening?

My HBASE VERSION IS 0.96 & HADOOP VERSION IS 1.2.1

Comment: have you checked logs?

Comment: I fixed it. I installed a different version of zoo keeper thinking its a compatibility issue. but there was already a root directory that was created by previous zookeeper. so there was a version clash & as a result Hmaster was quitting. I deleted the hbase default directory in HDFS & freshly started all demons. Worked like a charm.